# IOS9 Cordova: NETWORK_ERR

Tags: ios9, visual-studio-cordova

Apps deployed to IOS9 built using cordova are getting NETWORK_ERR. Same app work fine in IOS8.

Visual Studio 2015
Yosemite build server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a new security mechanism enforced by iOS 9: App Transport Security ATS

```
App Transport Security (ATS) enforces best practices in the secure connections between an app and its back end. ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt; it is also on by default in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one.

If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW14)

Altough not recommended, I got around this problem by using this plugin:

https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security.git